# React useEffect hook on number prop change to the same number

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I create react countdown component and it gets one prop - interval:

```
<Countdown interval={20} />
```

when rendered component starts to countdown passed seconds till reaches 0.
if I change that prop during counting, then it's recognized by useEffect hook with [interval] dependency and starting to countdown for the new interval.

I change it to 25, 30, 15 ....  and it all work, but
if I changed to 20 for example, waited for 10 secs and now I want again to start from 20,
therefor I'm trying to change that prop again to 20, expecting to see counting down from 20 to zero.

But coz it's the same number, so the change doesn't recognized by the hook and nothing happens.

In which way can I sort it out?

[image]

[image]

call from another component:

```
 <Time interval={time} isActive={isActive} onStop={timerStopped} />
```

change detection:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (timer.current) clearInterval(timer.current);
    setTimeLeft(interval);
    if (isActive) startTimer();
  }, [interval])
```

Comment: You definately need to give more detail on this.

Comment: one of the solutions I see is to add additional prop, kinda uid/current time and every time I change interval to change it too, so update will be recognized.

Comment: Why don't you just have a `reset` button there? Isn't clicking that `20` again might be more confusing than a button to reset?

Comment: Time has no buttons and serves digits display only, while getting props from outside and buttons are in the external component as well. So I can add reset button to the parent component, but what should it do?

Comment: My suggestion would be to add a `reset` button next to that `pause`. So if users would like to reset the current selected time, they then use that. Just like other stop-watch did.

Comment: after pressing reset button what is it going to do with the <Time> component? it has interval, isactive props only. I can stop it changing isActive prop, and I can change time by changing interval prop. But I can't change to the same time, it means I can actually but time component will not detect it